# Use Slider to Change Image CSS Filter with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-filters

I'm trying to change the css filter (hue-rotate to be exact) on a png by using a slider input. I keep getting "-webkit-filter:hue-rotate(**undefined**deg)"

Thanks for your help!

Here's my code:

```js
function hueFunction(hueVal) {
  var setAs = hueVal + "deg"
  document.getElementById("lgImage").setAttribute("style", "-webkit-filter:hue-rotate(" + setAs + ")")
}
```

```html
<input type="range" data-default="0" value="0" min="0" max="360" step="1" id="hue-rotate" oninput="hueFunction(this.hueVal)">

<br/>

<img src="https://campstoregear.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/summer-camp-2018-apparel-design-CD1816-Primary.png" id="lgImage">
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `oninput="hueFunction(this.hueVal)"` to `oninput="hueFunction(this.value)"`

```js
function hueFunction(hueVal) {
  var setAs = hueVal + "deg"
  document.getElementById("lgImage").setAttribute("style", "-webkit-filter:hue-rotate(" + setAs + ")")
}
```

```html
<input type="range" data-default="0" value="0" min="0" max="360" step="1" id="hue-rotate" oninput="hueFunction(this.value)">

<br/>

<img src="https://campstoregear.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/summer-camp-2018-apparel-design-CD1816-Primary.png" id="lgImage">
```

Comment: Do you know why this doesn't work with Classes instead of IDs? 
If I swap "getElementByID" for "getElementsByClassName" it dosn't work.

Comment: `getElementById` returns a single element, `getElementsByClassName` - an array of elements. You need to specify which one you want to use, like `getElementsByClassName('youClassName')[0]`  http://jsbin.com/piworezoco/edit?html,js,output

Comment: how would I apply this to all elements with that class?

Comment: with a `for` loop, for exampe.. http://jsbin.com/fopibigabu/edit?js,output

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!